# Show or hide div on device having GPS and/or location capabilities

Tags: css, browser, responsive-design, gps, mobile-website

About to launch a new website that has a really nice map which has a "use my location" feature.

This works OK for mobiles and tablets that have GPS and location capabilities, but for desktops and laptops (without GPS) it uses the ISP public IP server...  ie. if I'm in regional NSW, my computer's public IP from the ADSL2 connection is served from Pyrmont in Sydney, so when I use the "use my location" feature on the website, it lists contact details of offices near to Sydney, and not regional NSW where I am.

I was thinking the easiest way to overcome this is to hide the "use my location" element with a `display:hide;` style in the CSS and have it show for the various @media queries the responsive site uses, but this poses a problem for devices with really high resolutions (Surface Pro 4 for example) or computers with really low resolutions (small netbooks or computers of those with poor eyesight).

Is there a device query or way to detect GPS capabilities that can be used to show/hide elements in the CSS?

Facebook seems to be using something similar to what I'm after (for device detection at least - not GPS)...

[image: Facebook Device Activity]

Comment: Well Facebook's statement is somewhat misleading, since for example _IE on Windows 10_ can be both a tablet and a desktop. Their **Device Type** should be **Browser/OS Type**

Comment: Have you tried the `position.coords.accuracy` property? ... I'm guessing that will be your best option (using `navigator.geolocation`) and based on how many meters, you decide whether to use it or not.

Comment: It's not necessarily the Map (of features of it) that is the issue, it's actually a content block that pulls data from other areas based on either a user input postcode or the geolocation.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a device query or way to detect GPS capabilities that can be
>   used to show/hide elements in the CSS?

Here is a suggestion, using the [`Geolocation API`'s](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/Using_geolocation) [`Coordinates.accuracy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Coordinates) property

[Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/LGSon/3pu47uy5/3/)

```js
var a = 500;  /* max 500 meters */
if (navigator.geolocation) {
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition, showError, {
    enableHighAccuracy: true
  });
} else {
  document.getElementById("geo").innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
  hideGeo();
}
function showPosition(position) {
  document.getElementById("geo").innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude +
    "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude +
    "<br>Accuracy: " + position.coords.accuracy +
    "<br>Speed: " + position.coords.speed + " m/s" +
    "<br>Altitude: " + position.coords.altitude +
    "<br>Heading: " + position.coords.heading;
  hideGeo(position.coords.accuracy);
}
function showError(error) {
  var errorTypes = {
    0: "Unknown error",
    1: "Permission denied by user",
    2: "Position is not available",
    3: "Request timed out"
  };
  document.getElementById("geo").innerHTML = "Error: " + errorTypes[error.code];
  hideGeo();
}
function hideGeo(accuracy) {
  if (!accuracy || accuracy > a) {
    document.body.setAttribute('data-hide-geo','');
  }
}
```

```css
.geo {
  color: green;
}
body[data-hide-geo] .geo {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="geo" class="geo"></div>
```

---

*Updated*

If you want to go the "device detection route", check these out

- JS: https://github.com/hgoebl/mobile-detect.js/blob/master/mobile-detect.js
- PHP: https://github.com/serbanghita/Mobile-Detect
- ASP/PHP/JS: http://blog.mobileesp.com/
- Commercial: https://deviceatlas.com/
- Lightweight: https://www.google.com/search?q=Lightweight%20Device-Detection

**Note:** Devices with a GPS, for example, can take a minute or more to get a GPS fix, so less accurate data (IP location or wifi) may be returned to `getCurrentPosition()`.

Comment: Your JS Fiddle demo isn't really an option as Chrome asked if the site can use my location and if I answer 'allow' (which most people will) it does a WAN IP location.
It performs the same on the browser on my phone.
FYI - most of your links are broken except the mobileesp and google search.   The google search was useful though as it led to the discovery of a WP plug-in https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-mobile-detect/ that I'm going to test out

Comment: @ReeceDodds Updated my links ... and the fiddle demo is a sample how you can use the `accuracy` property, as that will tell within how many meters the accuracy of the return position is, hence if it is to much, don't show the geo info (my code rendered the text red in such case). And the users will always have to answer if to allow using their location.

Comment: @ReeceDodds Updated my answer with a note saying on a GPS capable device _...less accurate data (IP location or wifi) may be returned..._, making the `accuracy` property still valuable.

Comment: @ReeceDodds It would be interesting to know where you ended up with this

Answer (score 0):

You could checkout [Modernizr](https://modernizr.com/docs), I think it should be a nice clean way to achieve what you are looking for.

```
if (Modernizr.geolocation) {
    // device supports geolocation
} else {
    // device doesn't support geolocation
}
```

Good luck!

Comment: this one looks extremely powerful... might try it out and see how I go.  The new website is built on WordPress, and there is a WP plug-in port of Modernizr so I'll test it too.

Comment: @ReeceDodds The `Modernizr.geolocation` doesn't do more than `navigator.geolocation`, tell if it is supported (and the user need to allow it to be used). [Here is a version](https://jsfiddle.net/LGSon/3pu47uy5/4/) of my sample using Modernizr. You still need to use something else, like the `accuracy` I suggested, to decide whether the result is usable or not.